# Using form combo boxes apply a filter to a query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I think I am close to this one, but can't work out the filtering process.

```
tblIndex(PrimaryCat,SubCat,UserID,Year)
tblResults(SubCat,UserID)
```

My Form has two combo boxes and a button. ComboBox1 has tblIndex.PrimaryCat values and ComboBox2 has tblIndexYear values.

What I want is when the command button in the form is pressed, tblResults opens showing the list of SubCat and UserID values when the combobox values are used as a filter on tblIndex.

Does this make sense?

I have the recordsource of the form set to tblResults. I'm using this, just need to add in filtering somehow:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT SubCat, UserID " & _
         "FROM tblIndex " & _
         "WHERE PrimaryCat = [strCat] AND Year = [strYear] " & _
         "GROUP BY SubCat, UserID"

DoCmd.OpenQuery "strSQL"

End Sub
```

> EDIT:
>
> I'm not sure if I am allowed to answer my own question but I worked out a solution. I >used INTO to put the results into a temp table I can further manipulate using:
>
> Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
>
> Dim strSQL As String
>
> strSQL = "SELECT SubCat, UserID INTO tblTemp " & _
>               "FROM tblIndex  " & _
>               "WHERE PrimaryCat = '" & cboPrimaryCat.Value & "' AND Year = '" & >cboYear.Value & _
>               "' GROUP BY SubCat, UserID"
>
> DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
>
> End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out. Can't run SQL without first storing it in a query. Solution is:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
    Dim qdfCurr As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT SubCat, UserID " & _
             "FROM tblIndex " & _
             "WHERE PrimaryCat  = '" & strCat.Value & "' AND Year = '" & strYear.Value & _
             "' GROUP BY SubCat, UserID"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set qdfCurr = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("TempQuery")
    If Err.Number = 3265 Then
        Set qdfCurr = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("TempQuery")
    End If

    qdfCurr.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "TempQuery"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that this sould work. Working with temp tables is more complicated. Imagine that you have 50 queries with their corresponding temp table!

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT SubCat, UserID " & _
         "FROM tblIndex " & _
         "WHERE PrimaryCat = " & Forms!FormName![strCat] & " AND Year = " & Forms!FormName![strYear] " " & _
         "GROUP BY SubCat, UserID"

DoCmd.OpenQuery strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that originally, for the same reason you mentioned, but got Run-time error 7874: Microsoft access can't find the object 'strSQL'

Comment: Removing the " from DoCmd.OpenQuery "strSQL" gets past that, but then I get the same runtime error, but this tims it has the SQL statement "SELECT Subcat......" instead of "strSQL" as the object it can't find

Comment: that is because strSQL is a variable. You must write DoCmd.OpenQuery strSQL. If you write DoCmd.OpenQuery "strSQL" Access will try to find a query with name strSQL

Comment: This answer is wrong, as the original questioner found out -- DoCmd.OpenQuery works only with saved queries.

Comment: You are right, David. The simpliest solution is create a query and filter tblIndex: in the qbe grid, for PrimaryCat the where clause sould by: Forms!FormName![strCat]; for Year: Forms!FormName![strYear]
In the button_click only is necesary to do: docmd.openquery "qryName"